# how do I enter a sudo command when part of my password contains uppercase letters and numbers

Tags: password

Part of my password contains numbers and uppercase letters.  How can I know that I am correctly typing my password in a terminal when invoking `sudo`?

I am not very computer literate, so I would appreciate a simple explanation.

Comment: While you are typing the password, you can't tell if you are correctly typing your password. Once you hit `return` if the password is wrong `sudo` will tell you to try again and if it is correct the command will execute. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 14):

Changing case and adding numbers or other characters makes a password much more secure.  While it requires more care when entering it is done in exactly the same way as you enter it anywhere else in the system: using the shift key to enter capitals or special characters as required.

Terminal and most text-based password verifiers will not echo any keystrokes however, and this causes some confusion.  Just type the password as would normally with no errors and press enter.  Nothing whatsoever will appear on the screen while you are doing this.

Answer (score 5):

Having numbers and upper-case characters, or any other ASCII character for that matter, has no bearing whatsoever on whether or not `sudo` will be able to handle your password. If you can type it on your keyboard, you can use it in your password.

The only practical difference between the `sudo` password prompt and a normal terminal session is that you can't see what you're typing with `sudo`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `sudo` for some GUI programs, you can try `gksudo` which gives you a GUI to enter password, which atleast shows how much characters you have typed, just like any other password field.

Comment: Interesting - have not heart of it before. However not only gui programs can be launched with gksudo - tested on ls in terminal.